# Filter functionality Project using C#

Tags: c#

I am simply implementing a filter function for one my forms. I'd like to hear some reviews where I can improve in my code or my functionality  :)

**Summary**

I have 1 textbox and 2 comboboxes (See image below):

[image]

**Category options**

[image]

**Status options**

[image]

**Code**

```
public MainView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    categoryText.SelectedIndex = 0;
    statusText.SelectedIndex = 0;

    RefreshData();
}

List<ConcessionModel> concessionList = new List<ConcessionModel>();
public void RefreshData()
{
    DataAccess db = new DataAccess();
    concessionList = db.LoadConcessionLog();
    dataGrid.DataSource = concessionList;

    dataGrid.Columns["Id"].Visible = false;
    dataGrid.Columns["PersonCompletingID"].Visible = false;
}


private void searchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGrid.DataSource = Filter(productText.Text, categoryText.Text, statusText.Text);
}

private List<ConcessionModel> Filter(string product, string category, string status)
{
    if (category == "All" && status != "All")
    {
        return concessionList
                .Where(x => x.Product
                .IndexOf(product, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 && x.Status
                .IndexOf(status, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                .ToList();
    }
    else if (category != "All" && status == "All")
    {
        return concessionList
                .Where(x => x.Product
                .IndexOf(product, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 && x.Category
                .IndexOf(category, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                .ToList();
    }
    else if(category == "All" && status == "All")
    {
        return concessionList
                .Where(x => x.Product
                .IndexOf(product, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        return concessionList
                .Where(x => x.Product
                .IndexOf(product, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 && x.Category
                .IndexOf(category, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0 && x.Status
                .IndexOf(status, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                .ToList();
    }
}

public void ClearConcessionFilter()
{
    productText.Clear();
    categoryText.SelectedIndex = 0;
    statusText.SelectedIndex = 0;
    dataGrid.DataSource = concessionList;
}
```

**ConcessionModel**

```
public class ConcessionModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Date Created")]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public int PersonCompletingID { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Batch Number")]
    public string BatchNumber { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Quantity Affected")]
    public string QuantityAffected { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Reason For Concession")]
    public string ReasonForConcession { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share with us the class definition of the `ConcessionModel`?

Comment: @PeterCsala No problem, give me 1 minute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me focus on the `Filter` method.

- There are a lot of repetitions in that method, which makes your code

  - harder to maintain

    - for example: replacing `IndexOf` to `Equals`
    - or by changing the `StringComparison` option to another
  - and more error-prone

    - for example: it is easy to misspell the `All` at one of the occurrences.

There are a couple of useful techniques that can make your code less error-prone and easier to change:

- Using constants, like: `const string all = "All";`
- Using single return, like: `return concessionList.Where(predicate).ToList();`
- Extracting common logic, like:

```
static bool IsPresent(string source, string target)
   => source.IndexOf(target, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
```

- Using default values instead of fallback,

  - like: `predicate` can have default value instead of relying on a
    final `else` block.

With these in our hand the `Filter` method could be rewritten like this:

```cs
private List<ConcessionModel> Filter(string product, string category, string status)
{
    const string all = "All";

    static bool IsPresent(string source, string target) 
        => source.IndexOf(target, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;

    Func<ConcessionModel, bool> predicate = model =>
        IsPresent(model.Product, product) &&
        IsPresent(model.Category, category) && 
        IsPresent(model.Status, status);

    if (category == all && status != all)
    {
        predicate = model =>
            IsPresent(model.Product, product) &&
            IsPresent(model.Status, status);
    }
    else if (category != all && status == all)
    {
        predicate = model =>
            IsPresent(model.Product, product) &&
            IsPresent(model.Category, category);
    }
    else if (category == all && status == all)
    {
        predicate = model =>
            IsPresent(model.Product, product);
    }
    
    return concessionList.Where(predicate).ToList();
}
```

- `predicate`: I've defined a function variable (`Func<TInput, TOutput>`)

  - It receives a `ConcessionModel` (as `TInput`)
  - and will return with a `bool` (as `TOutput`).
- So, I have defined a function which implementation varies based on the input parameters.
- We use this function as a filter condition (`Where`) against the data source (`concessionList`)

  - Here I have used the short form, but could be written like this:

    - `return concessionList.Where(model => predicate(model)).ToList();`

Comment: The `Func<ConcessionModel, bool> predicate = model` is not something I have seen before, are you able to explain please to what is going in? :)

Comment: @LV98 I've extended my answer, please check it again.

Comment: Quick question.. let's say I had a boolean value in my Model called `Archived`. New parameter will be added in the Filter as `bool archived`, but the `IsPresent` will show an error that it cannot convert from `bool to string`. How would you alter the current code you have?

Comment: @LV98 `IsPresent` was designed for string comparison. If you want to filter via an additional bool variable then you can do something like this:  `predicate = model => IsPresent(model.Product, product) && model.Archived == archived`. Does it answer your question?

Comment: Ah I see... Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This approach is IMHO a bad idea. Already your code is barely maintainable and contains numerous copy-pasted sections.

You should pass a "filter" (a custom class) to `LoadConcessionLog()` (bad method name, BTW) and let the `IQueryable` handle the various filters (I'm assuming you use Entity Framework), along the lines of [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/167507/10582) (or one of the other answers on that page). Let your query apply the necessary filters, so the data that is returned from the DB is already limited.

---

If you're using Dapper, then you can still apply similar logic. You can either construct the `WHERE` clause in code, or you could write an SQL query that has a `WHERE` clause that [takes this into account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2329692/648075).

If you take the second approach, you could have a query with a WHERE like this;

```
WHERE 1 = 1
   AND (@Category IS NULL OR Category = @Category)
   AND (@Status IS NULL OR Status = @Status)
```

You then pass for instance `new { Category = category, Status = status }` where `category` and `status` are `string`s which could contain a value or be `null`.

---

The main ideas are:

- let your database do the filtering
- write your code in an extendible way, where adding a new filter doesn't require you to copy-paste blocks of logic.

Consider for instance that you need to add a third filter. In your current code you need to rethink all the `if`/`else` logic, you need to add this third filter to each scenario, plus you need to take into account new combinations,... It is a nightmare to maintain. Whereas if you apply my logic, you simply need to add a property to your filter class, you need to adapt the `WHERE` clause, you need to pass the new filter in your Dapper call, and that is all.

And you might think: well, isn't this overkill when I only need two filters? Perhaps. But the advantage is you learn skills that you can later apply in bigger projects.

---

It is also odd that you use `IndexOf` when comparing `Category` or `Status`; I'd expect those comparisons to necessitate an "equals". What if you get a new status called "Reopened": now that also matches "Open" in your logic.

Also, consider normalizing your database. "Category" could be a table of its own, and its ID would then be a foreign key in your Products table. Same for "Status", although that might also be an `enum`. ("Category" could be an `enum` as well, of course.)

Comment: I am using dapper instead of Entity, sorry should of mentioned.

Comment: @LV98 I have added a section WRT Dapper as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another simpler way of doing the filter :

```
private bool EqualsOrSource(string source, string target, bool required)
{   
    var result = target == "All"  && !required ? source : target;

    return source.Equals(result, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
}

private List<ConcessionModel> Filter(string product, string category, string status)
{
    return concessionList
        .Where(x => EqualsOrSource(x.Product, product, true) // required
    &&  EqualsOrSource(x.Category, category) // optional 
    &&  EqualsOrSource(x.Status, status)  // optional 
    ).ToList();
}
```